# Creating a new folder and access it via web application

Tags: java, linux, file, permissions, websphere-liberty

I have this IBM Liberty webserver running on a Linux environment under a user call appserver.
I want to create a new folder outside the application structure and access it from Web UI.

The issue I´m having is, upon creation the new folder is not visible to the web server, forcing me to restart the web server.
The new folder is created with permission 770 and the user that creates the new folder is part of the same appserver group. This is an example of a new folder created by a given user, i.e: /home/someuser/import

On UI, I select this folder but upon verification, the folder does not exist. But if I restart the web server, the folder becomes accessible.

Is there any way I can get this to work without restarting the webserver and changing the folder permission(770)?

Comment: Please share more information, what have you did so far, snippets if you have etc..

Comment: From the UI, when the user tries to save the new folder, I do a check on it using java nio.
This is when I get the folder does not exist. 
If I check if the file exist and then it it has read/write permission. But the error starts from checking if the folder exists. Let me know if you need more details.